# Displaying workflow history using Javascript in SP2007

Tags: list, 2007, library, workflow-history

I have a document library and a item list that have one workflow for each of them in a SharePoint 2007 site.

May I know if there is any ways for me to retrieve the workflow history for both the library and the list using Javascript? (cause I have some data in the list that refer to some data in the library and vice-versa)